# A telnet program that supports batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, telnet

I need a telnet program that supports cmd.exe windows.

For example, if I type in cmd

```
telnet
```

I am getting an error like this as below
[image]

The telnet program runs inside the current cmd window.

SSH support if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Source [Telnet: frequently asked questions](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/telnet-faq#1TC=windows-7)

> **How do I install Telnet?**
>
> By default, Telnet is not installed with Windows, but you can install
>   it by following the steps below.
>
> To install Telnet Client
>
> - Click the Start button Picture of the Start button, click Control Panel, and then click Programs.
> - Under Programs and Features, click Turn Windows features on or off. Administrator permission required If you're prompted for an
>     administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide
>     confirmation.
> - In the Windows Features dialog box, select the Telnet Client check box.
> - Click OK. The installation might take several minutes.